# How can i call the number from the list that has been created?

Tags: c, list, if-statement, pointers

```
        printf("Enter birthday: day>");
        scanf(" %02d", &list[*number_of_employee].birthday.day);  
        if (number >30 || number < 0) {
            printf("Invalid day.\n");
        }
```

My issue is the variable "number" I do not know how to replace it with the list that is provided so it can be a number valid for the boolean comparison.

thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your problem a little bit clearer?

Comment: You need to check the return of `scanf()` is equal to `1`. You have `list[*number_of_employee].birthday.day` if the conversion succeeds, so just `if (list[*number_of_employee].birthday.day > 30 || list[*number_of_employee].birthday.day < 0) { .. }`

Comment: @RohanBari the number i just scanned in, I want to see if it is within the parameters of the if statement.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin 's comment is the right answer. Just replace `number` in your code with `list[*number_of_employee].birthday.day`